# How to insert a block of html into a java servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm messing around with some java source in eclipse for an existing appengine site. I want to get one of the existing pages to show a google earth plugin applet.

I have this little snippet that works in an html file but I cant figure out how to get the servlet to put this into the html that it generates.

I am not really a coder so I need some pretty consice instructions on how to get java to make this work.

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://code.google.com/apis/kml/embed/tourgadget.xml&amp;up_kml_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebfiles.colorado.edu%2Fwww%2FLSF%2520DB%2520Placemarks5.kmz&amp;up_tour_index=1&amp;up_tour_autoplay=1&amp;up_show_navcontrols=1&amp;up_show_buildings=1&amp;up_show_terrain=1&amp;up_show_roads=0&amp;up_show_borders=1&amp;up_sphere=earth&amp;synd=open&amp;w=700&amp;h=600&amp;title=Embedded+Tour+Player&amp;border=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gmodules.com%2Fig%2Fimages%2F&amp;output=js"></script>
```

===

```
protected void beginBasicHtmlResponse(String pageName, String headContent, HttpServletResponse resp,
      HttpServletRequest req, boolean displayLinks) throws IOException {
resp.addHeader(HOST_HEADER, getServerURL(req));
resp.setContentType(ServletConsts.RESP_TYPE_HTML);
resp.setCharacterEncoding(ServletConsts.ENCODE_SCHEME);
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
out.write(HtmlConsts.HTML_OPEN);
out.write("<link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/odk_color.png\">");
out.write(HtmlUtil.wrapWithHtmlTags(HtmlConsts.HEAD, headContent + HtmlUtil.wrapWithHtmlTags(
    HtmlConsts.TITLE, BasicConsts.APPLICATION_NAME)));
out.write(HtmlConsts.BODY_OPEN);
out.write(HtmlUtil.wrapWithHtmlTags(HtmlConsts.H2, "<FONT COLOR=330066 size=0><img src='/odk_color.png'/>" + HtmlConsts.SPACE + BasicConsts.APPLICATION_NAME) + "</FONT>");
if (displayLinks) {
  UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
  out.write(generateNavigationInfo());
  out.write(HtmlConsts.TAB + HtmlConsts.TAB);
  out.write(HtmlUtil.createHref(userService.createLogoutURL("/"), "Log Out from "
      + userService.getCurrentUser().getNickname()));
  out.write(HtmlConsts.TAB + "<FONT SIZE=1>" + ServletConsts.VERSION + "</FONT>");
}
out.write(HtmlConsts.LINE_BREAK + HtmlConsts.LINE_BREAK);
out.write(HtmlUtil.wrapWithHtmlTags(HtmlConsts.H1, pageName));
```

}

Comment: Have you identified the bit of code that ouputs the existing HTML? If so can you  post it here?

Answer (score 4):

Yet another method would be using **Request Dispatcher**:

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Included HTML block:");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/pathToFile/block.html").include(request, response); 
    out.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a servlet, then the easiest thing that comes to my mind is the following:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("put your snippet here");
}
```

Essentially:

- in your servlet you need to get a `PrintWriter` from the `response` object that you receive as parameter in the `doGet()` method
- everything you print on that `PrintWriter` will be sent to the browser

Warning: be careful at not messing up what your servlet is already sending to the browser.

---

After seeing the code you added to your question, I think you can add your snippet after the line

```
out.write(HtmlConsts.BODY_OPEN);
```

by adding

```
out.write("<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://code.google.com/apis/kml/embed/tourgadget.xml&amp;up_kml_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebfiles.colorado.edu%2Fwww%2FLSF%2520DB%2520Placemarks5.kmz&amp;up_tour_index=1&amp;up_tour_autoplay=1&amp;up_show_navcontrols=1&amp;up_show_buildings=1&amp;up_show_terrain=1&amp;up_show_roads=0&amp;up_show_borders=1&amp;up_sphere=earth&amp;synd=open&amp;w=700&amp;h=600&amp;title=Embedded+Tour+Player&amp;border=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gmodules.com%2Fig%2Fimages%2F&amp;output=js"></script>")
```

Comment: Then I past that in the code, a  red line comes up under servletexception, and when I try to run it nothing is different. Also, in the servlet code there is a "protected void" section that seems to contain the chunk where I want the google earth aplet to go. How would I insert your snippet into that?

Comment: OK: the `protected void ...` is probably a method of your servlet class. If you think that's the point where you need to add your snippet, then it may be useful if you copy the `protected void ...` method in the question: this would allow us to better assist you.

Comment: Thanks marco, I posted it, what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use jsp for view.  Use servlet as just controller

**See Also**

- [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: This is a good idea. However I'm afraid our friend m13124 is not interested at the moment in a clean separation of model-view-controller (he says he's not a coder). It looks like he just wants to modify an existing servlet to quickly do what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

close the scripting code... with %>
then you can write anything you want in plain html

and after that open the scripting tag again
<%

that should be it

Comment: What so you mean exactly? Where do I put those %>?

Comment: that would work if you had a jsp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what your looking for. i use this in java EE doPost block.
or perhaps u can use this as reference for the equivalent syntax to what your looking for.

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.print("<html>");
    out.print("<head>");
    out.print("<title>");
    out.print("</title>");
    out.print("<h1>view accounts</h1>");
    out.print("</head>");
```